# Create new 'super-category' in iTunes heirachy

Tags: itunes, music, folders

In iTunes, I have many audio files which aren't music. In my case they are guitar tutorial tracks, but others may have similar things which are for language learning or self-help/hypnosis tracks.

[image]

I don't want these lumped in with the rest of my music, as I find they clutter up my music collection, make it hard to find things and makes playing my music on 'shuffle' a strange experience.

I know I can untick the songs to prevent them from being played, or create some kind of playlist for the songs I do want to play, but these are not ideal solutions.

Is there a way of removing them from the 'Music' super-folder altogether, ideally creating a new super-folder just for them? (By super-folder I mean the 'Music', 'Movies' and 'TV Shows' categories that appear on the left).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the items and get the item information by pressing `Command+I`. Choose `Options` tab and change the **Media Kind** to the suitable category. It doesn’t let you create a new category, but the some of existing categories should fit to your media (perhaps using iTunes U or Audiobook).

[image: Media Kind in iTunes 10]